# Modules that rely on each other

Tags: python, django, django-forms, decorator, python-decorators

I have a `bind_form` custom decorator that assigns a specified django form to a function. This decorator will allow validation to be 'automatically' performed on function arguments - e.g., check if `age` is in required range, or check that user exists. This is done for DRY reasons.

Each form that is referenced in the decorator live in the `forms` module.

An example of this form validation could be `users.check_user_exists` - and hence I must import the `users` module in the `form` module.

So, now you see that I have `forms` module, that imports the `users` module so `users.user_exists` can be referenced, but `users` imports the `forms` module so a form can be used in the forms decorator:

**forms.py:**

```
import users

def bind_form(func):
    # binds form to function
    ...

class Create_User(Forms.Form):
    # validated create_user function
    ...
    def clean(self): #using for validation
        if users.user_exists(user):
           ...
```

**users.py:**

```
import forms

@forms.bind_form(form=forms.Create_User)
def create_user(**kwargs):
    ...
```

so as soon as `users` is imported, `users` attempts to reference `bind_form`, but this has not been 'seen' yet by `forms`.

Is this a design flaw of mine, or am I missing something simple? If a design flaw - suggestions welcome to improve.

** constraints:**

- there are many forms in the `forms` module.
- there are many functions in `users` module that have a validation form attached.
- the validation forms use many functions from `users`, and other modules.

**explained in another way:**

a. `forms` imports `users` at line 4 of `forms` module

b. `users.create_user` references `forms.Create_User`

c. `forms` doesnt know about `Create_User` yet becasue it's declared on line 5 of `forms` module

Comment: It depends if you ever reference the symbol `users` in the global scope of `forms.py`. Since your example doesn't seem to reference it at all, it's difficult to tell. ;)

Comment: I am being affected by the problem - its not a hypothetical, unfortunately.

Comment: I never said it was hypothetical, I meant your code examples don't provide sufficient information to give a specific answer.

Comment: Should I assume that the line in `forms.py` which reads `if user_exists(user)` should actually read `if users.check_user_exists(user)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with cyclic dependencies is to separate the statements in the global scope, such that all the statements which don't reference any symbols imported from the other module all occur before you import it. For example...

**forms.py:**

```
# This statement doesn't reference 'users' at compile time
def bind_form(func):
    ...

# This statement doesn't reference 'users' at compile time
class Create_User(Forms.Form):

    # This statement declares a new scope
    def clean(self):

        # This statement references 'users' at runtime, but not at compile time
        if users.user_exists(user):
            ...

# Now import
import users
```

**users.py:**

```
# Import
import forms

# This statement references 'forms' at compile time
@forms.bind_form(form=forms.Create_User)
def create_user(**kwargs):
    ...
```

The usage of the `users` symbol in the `Create_User.clean()` method is not in the global scope, so it doesn't actually need the symbol to be defined until the point where the function is actually called.

Comment: in your answer `forms.Create_User` hasn't been declared at the point where `users` is impoted, so it cant be referenced by `users.create_user`. We could expand on your answer and say "import `users` at the end of `forms` module", but that wouldn't work as `forms` references functions in `users`

Comment: Forgot it only matters in global scope. Updated answer.

Comment: as explained in the comment above yours 'We could expand on your answer and say "import users at the end of forms module", but that wouldn't work as forms references functions in users'

Comment: Wait. Is the line `if users.user_exists(user)` directly inside the `class Create_User(Forms.Form)`, or should there be a method in there somewhere?

Comment: its used inside a method. I cut down the code somewhat. Does this change anything? If so I can put it in the method in the question.

Comment: Yeah. It makes a huge difference, because it's not used in the **global scope**.

Comment: The answer should work, for the reason I mentioned at the bottom of it. The point is that it's fine to use undefined symbols inside functions and methods, because they have their own scope, so the `Create_User.clean()` method won't care whether you've imported `users` or not.

Comment: NP. I knew it would work, because I've had to do it many times before - it's just really difficult to explain. :/

Comment: indeed, I have the same problem! we got there in the end :)